# Bootstrap: Can I Automatically Break Content into Separate Columns by Setting a Max-Height on the Parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on creating a horizontal navbar that has dropdowns in Bootstrap. The dropdowns are really long, so I'd like to break the results into three separate columns stacked side-by-side. I don't want my dropdowns to have a height beyond 350px. This would be simple enough if I could just organize the dropdown list items into three separate divs, each with a class `col-lg-4` (since this particular navbar style only appears on screens 1200px and above), except that the entire contents of the navbar are loaded dynamically via AJAX and are subject to change.

I can think of some less-than-elegant approaches to this issue, using JavaScript to count the length of the list and then divide that number and wrap said number of elements in separate divs (this would keep the height below 350px almost always), but I can't help but think there must be a better way.

Is there some way I can set the `max-height` of the dropdown (an `ul` element), set the width of the `li` elements inside using `class="col-lg-4"`, and have the overflow content carry over into a new column? I suspect I must be missing something very obvious.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), assuming your users are using [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vjpv10xx/)